# How to stop unwanted whitespace appearing in output following Xslt transformation

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm using VS2008 to write and test an xsl transformation. The output contains unwanted white space as illustrated by this simplified example:

Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<envelope>
  <header>
    <head id="1" text="Heading1"/>
  </header>
  <body>
    <message>
      <items>
        <item id="1" Color="Red"/>
        <item id="2" Color="Green"/>
        <item id="3" Color="Blue"/>
        <item id="4" Color="Purple"/>
      </items>
    </message>
  </body>
</envelope>
```

Transformation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="message">
    <xsl:element name="Colors">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="items/item" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="items/item">
    <xsl:element name="Color">
      <xsl:value-of select="@Color"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>




        <Colors><Color>Red</Color><Color>Green</Color><Color>Blue</Color><Color>Purple</Color></Colors>
```

Whilst its difficult to show in the output, what seems to be happening is whitespace from the input file is being sent to the output file even when my template doesn't match. This is what I'd like and expect the output to look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Colors>
  <Color>Red</Color>
  <Color>Green</Color>
  <Color>Blue</Color>
  <Color>Purple</Color>
</Colors>
```

Is this possible? What I may have to do now is to load the result into an Xml document, then write it out again formatted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the unwanted whitespace, adding this template should do the trick:

```
<xsl:template match="text()"/>
```

It means "ignore all text nodes".

For the pretty-printing, the `indent` attribute on your `output` element should work. I'm not sure why it is being ignored and everything is on the same line. Perhaps a Microsoft issue?

Comment: Formatting works exactly as requested using that template for me in Saxon

Comment: Might be able to force the newlines in using <xsl:text>(newline-here!)</xsl:text>